# python csv - print duplicate account number with counter

Tags: python, csv, row, counter

can someone help me setup a counter? i read you can use `Counter` to show a count of any value. but i would like to print the count as the row iterates.

here is an example of my file:

```
A12000,NAME
A12000,NAME
A12000,NAME
A13000,NAME
A14000,NAME
A15000,NAME
```

i would like to print:

```
1,A12000,NAME
2,A12000,NAME
3,A12000,NAME
1,A13000,NAME
1,A14000,NAME
1,A15000,NAME
```

this is what i have:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('O:/csvdocs/count1.csv', 'rb') as cf:
    rr = csv.reader(cf)

    for row in rr:
        acctnum = []
        acctnum.append(row[0])
        acctcounter = Counter(acctnum)

        print acctcounter
```

this is what prints:

```
Counter({'A12000': 1})
Counter({'A12000': 1})
Counter({'A12000': 1})
Counter({'A13000': 1})
Counter({'A14000': 1})
Counter({'A15000': 1})
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to create *one* `Counter` and *one* `list` for all lines, for example:

```
with open('O:/csvdocs/count1.csv', 'rb') as cf:
    rr = csv.reader(cf)
    acctnum = [] # outside loop
    for row in rr:
        acctnum.append(row[0])
    acctcounter = Counter(acctnum) # also outside loop
    print acctcounter
```

Comment: this only prints the counter total. is there a way to print each counter as it iterates ie: 1,2,3: `1,A12000,NAME` `2,A12000,NAME` `3,A12000,NAME`

Comment: Yes, if you add to the counter instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter                                    
with open('O:/csvdocs/count1.csv', 'rb') as cf:                                
    count =  Counter(cf.readlines())        

with open("file.csv",'wb') as w:
    [[w.write("{},{}".format(i,key)) for i in range(1,count[key]+1)] for key in count]
```

Comment: for `A12000,NAME` i would like to print/write a new line with each counter: 1,2,3 ie: `1,A12000,NAME` `2,A12000,NAME` `3,A12000,NAME` not the counter total